# Provisioning profile change when taking the app from adhoc stage to app store distribution when using APNS

Tags: ios, xcode, ssl, app-store, ad-hoc-distribution

I am having this little trouble understanding the stage. I built a product which requires to use APNS service. I built it using a adhoc profile with Production SSL certificate of APNS. The app is doing well in 4 of my devices.

Now I want to distribute it to app store, my question is that do I need to revoke the SSL certificate and create a new one (with all steps to create .pem file) and then make provisioning profile for app store or use the same (pem files used in Adhoc distribution) and just create the provisioning profile (app store distribution) using the same app-id?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to revoke the certificate.  If your server is using the production APNS certificate  to push notifications, you are in good shape.  You will need to create an App Store distribution provisioning profile using an iOS distribution certificate (not the APNS certificate).  Use this new profile to archive and submit your app.

Comment: So you mean to say I don't need to go through the procedure again to generate .pem file from(CSR and P12 file using distribution certificate), I will just make a provisioning profile for app store distribution will be good to go?

Comment: Yes, you only need to recreate it if you used the development APNS certificate previously.